# Why isn't my function able to determine whether or not a char is a vowel?

Tags: c++, function, error-handling, parameter-passing

I am making a basic program to count the vowels of a string. I wanted to try using a bool function to test if each char is a vowel, but whenever I enter the string with vowels, it doesn't increase the `vowels` int.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char){
 char chara;
 return (tolower(chara) == 'a' || tolower(chara) == 'e' || 
   tolower(chara) == 'i' || tolower(chara) == 'o' || 
   tolower(chara) == 'u' || tolower(chara) == 'y');
}

int main()
{
   string input;
   int vowels = 0;

   cin >> input;

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){
      if( isVowel(input.at(i)) )
         vowels++;
   }
   cout << "Including a, e, i, o, u, and y, that word contains " << vowels << " vowels.\n";
}
```

For example, when I enter "hello" as input into the console, the `vowels` integer has the value of 0. What is wrong about my function?

Comment: `chara` is an uninitialized variable, separate from and unrelated to the function argument (which you neglected to name, and so cannot refer to). You may want to consult your favorite C++ 101 textbook on how to implement functions.

Comment: A good compiler would be able to warn you about the use of the uninitialized variable. If your compiler doesn't do that now, then you need to enable more warnings when building. And I really recommend that you treat just about all warnings as errors.

Comment: BTW, I think that `const auto vowels = std::count_if(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), [](const char c){ return isVowel(c);});` also works and is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax for function parameters wrong, and inadvertently wrote something that was legal, but didn't do what you expected it to. Write it like this

```
bool isVowel(char chara) {
    return chara == 'A' || chara == 'E' || 
        chara == 'I' || chara == 'O' || chara == 'U' || chara == 'Y' || 
        chara == 'a' || chara == 'e' || chara == 'i' || chara == 'o' || 
        chara == 'u' || chara == 'y';
}
```